# How to reply in case of synchronous messaging using Spring AMQP?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have code using Spring AMQP for synchronous messaging as below. My scenario is when producer sends messages it is expecting response. So, can any one help on how to send response back in case of synchronous messages.

```
Producer end - rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(object);
Consumer end - rabbitTemplate.receiveAndconvert();
```

and I came know that we can use `handleMessage()` in case of asynchronous messaging. But, using above API  how to send response back in case of synchronous messaging? Can you please help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about to use this one `convertSendAndReceive`?
In this case the `RabbitTemplate` takes care about synchronius send request and receive a reply.
Try it, please and let us know

Comment: Hi Bilan, yes.. we can use convertSendAndReceive() at producer end. what about consumer end, I mean how can we send response back in reply queue? Can you please share me.

Comment: Sorry for deply. You should use `MessageListener`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#request-reply. Or just get `replyToAddress` from received message and send response to that address. However we work now under some convenient `receiveAndReply`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/pull/138

Comment: Thanks for the comment, introduction of method receiveAndReply will be very convenient, will this be available in 1.3.0 Release right? when it will be available for the developers?

Comment: Yes, that feature is really planed to 1.3.0. We are going to release it somewhere about January 10

Answer (score 2):

See the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html#request-reply) for options.

The `convertSendAndReceive` on the producer side adds a `replyTo` header (default is a new temporary queue but you can configure a fixed reply queue).

On the consumer side, the simplest solution is to a message listener container and the `MessageListenerAdapter` will call your simple POJO and take care of sending the reply for you.

If you must use a rabbit template on the consumer side, you would need to use a lower level `receive` to get access to the message properties, so you can access the `replyTo` information in order to send the reply.

Take a look at the source code for the `MessageListenerAdapter` to see how he does it.

Comment: at consumer side I have used simplemessagelistenercontainer which registering with simple POJO which is having handleMessage() where it will return some object  that will be received at producer side using convertSendAndReceive method. As per my understanding all this process is called Asynchronous messaging right? 

In case of synchronous messages, do I need to use receive() method for receiving the messages and send() method for sending response to replyTo queue?

Comment: In the first case when I use convertSendAndReceive method and running multiple requests where each producer sends messages and receives response from handleMessage which is there at consumer end. But, while running above test case we are getting Any reason for getting this exception? And how can we confirm that am getting correct response for request?